# In French, how do you say idiomatically "No questions are off limits"?

Tags: expressions, traduction, anglais

In order to check to see if there were some particular topics that we didn't want them to touch upon on camera, they asked us beforehand if we would consider some questions *uncalled for*. Then I wanted to say something along the lines of:

> **No questions are off limits**. So please feel free to fire away any question you may have.

I wonder if there is an idiomatic phrasing in French that comes in handy in a situation like this?

Comment: *Tout va plus?*

Comment: Il n'y a pas de question idiote.

Answer (score 6):

> *Aucune question n'est taboue.*
>
> *Aucun sujet n'est tabou.*
>
> *Aucune question n'est malvenue.*

Answer (score 3):

You could say something like:

> On peut parler de tout
>
> On peut parler sans tabou
>
> Pas de tabou entre nous
>
> Je n'ai rien à cacher

Comment: L'expression _Je n'ai rien à cacher_ porte sur les éventuelles réponses, alors que l'original en anglais fait explicitement référence aux questions, sans présupposer si des reponses seront apportées.

Comment: @mouviciel Dans l'expression anglaise, il y a un engagement implicite à répondre.

Answer (score 0):

> Toutes les questions sont permises.

Answer (score -1):

(Il n'y aura) aucune censure sur les questions.

[Wikipedia](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Censure) : La censure est la limitation arbitraire ou doctrinale de la liberté d'expression de chacun.

Comment: Pas vraiment. La censure ne s'appliquerait que s'il s'agissait de publier les questions. On ne peut pas censurer les questions _avant_ que les gens les posent.

Comment: Oui, c'est pourquoi j'ai mis le sous entendu 'il n'y aura'. On annonce que ce ne sera pas censuré.

Comment: Peu importe que le sens de la phrase est formellement correct : personne ne dirait ça.

Comment: "Personne ne dirait ça" est une affirmation gratuite. Dites modestement "je ne l'ai jamais entendu" et ça ira mieux...   Trouvé en 2mn sur un site de forum : "venez vous installer chez nous vous ne serez pas censuré". Ça couvre aussi la remarque sur le futur.